# Как правильно сделать функцию обновить объект в массиве?

Tags: typescript, generics

есть два масива обьектов. Нужно функцию которая будет принимать масив обьектов(initialArray), искать по айдишке(keyToFind) нужний обьект и к свойству(keyValueToFind) присвоить новое значение(patch)

```
type Users = {
id:number;
name:string;
passExam:boolean
}
type Posts = {
id:number;
body:string;
rate:number
}

function updateObjectInArray<T>(
    initialArray: T[],
     keyToFind:keyof T, 
     keyValueToFind:keyof T, 
     patch:typeof T[keyValueToFind]) {
   
        return initialArray.map(obj => obj.id == keyToFind? {...obj, keyValueToFind: patch}: obj)
}
updateObjectInArray<Users>(arr1, 3, 'name', 'Alex')//сменит имья в обьекте с id3
updateObjectInArray<Posts>(arr2, 2, 'rate', 34) // сменит свойство rate на 34 в обьекте с id==2
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: что не так с кодом в вопросе? Покажи пример, как ты хочешь использовать эту функцию

Comment: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'T'.ts(2339)

Comment: ты никак не ограничиваешь тип T соответственно свойство `id` может и не быть, поэтому и ошибка.

Comment: initialArray.map(obj => obj[keyToFind] == keyToFind? {...obj, keyValueToFind: patch}: obj)  - дает ошибку This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'keyof T' and 'T[keyof T]' have no overlap.

Comment: ну так ты сравниваешь имя ключа и значение по этому ключу :) определись, что именно должен делать твой метод

Comment: так как сделать чтоб работало? есть только такие аргументы  initialArray, keyToFind ,keyValueToFind, patch - есть только такие аргументы

Comment: _Покажи пример, как ты хочешь использовать эту функцию_ - сейчас непонятно что у тебя аргументы функции значат. Отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки [edit]

Comment: надеюсь, должно бить понятно.

Comment: не, покажи с какими параметрами ты это все будет вызывать и какой результат ожидаешь.

Comment: исходя из примера использования - неверно даны имена параметрам, и соответственно неверно указаны их типы, например `keyToFind` это `id` элемента и он всегда `number`. в остальном все работает, если укажешь, что в типе T может быть поле `id`